# Can I use author-year citation with multi-bib

Tags: labels, multibib

I want to have a bibliography that is referenced using author-year style. There should be *no labels*. However, I cannot figure out, how to do this with multi-bib. I tried to use `\usepackage[round]{natbib}`, but then latex tells me that the 'Bibliography is not compatible with author-year citations.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{A}{References2}

\begin{document}
Reference without prefix \cite{Creighton2006} and a reference with prefix \citeA{Johnson2000}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{library}                 

\bibliographystyleA{plain}
\bibliographyA{library}                   

\end{document}
```

The library bibtex file with the two references looks as follows:

```
@article{Johnson2000,
author = {Johnson, W Lewis and Rickel, Jeff W and Lester, James C},
journal = {International Journal of Artificial Intelligence in Education},
number = {11},
pages = {47--78},
title = {{Animated pedagogical agents: face-to-face interaction in interactive learning environments}},
volume = {Internatio},
year = {2000}
}
@inproceedings{Creighton2006,
author = {Creighton, Oliver and Ott, Martin and Bruegge, Bernd},
booktitle = {Requirements Engineering, 14th IEEE International Conference},
isbn = {0769525555},
pages = {109--118},
publisher = {IEEE},
title = {{Software cinema-video-based requirements engineering}},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs{\_}all.jsp?arnumber=1704054},
year = {2006}
}
```

Comment: I added them below as separate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your given code you should change style `plain` to `plainnat`.

With the following MWE named `mwe.tex`

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Creighton2006,
  author    = {Creighton, Oliver and Ott, Martin and Bruegge, Bernd},
  booktitle = {Requirements Engineering, 14th IEEE International Conference},
  isbn      = {0769525555},
  pages     = {109--118},
  publisher = {IEEE},
  title     = {{Software cinema-video-based requirements engineering}},
  url       = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs{\_}all.jsp?arnumber=1704054},
  year      = {2006},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{A.bib}
@article{Johnson2000,
  author  = {Johnson, W Lewis and Rickel, Jeff W and Lester, James C},
  journal = {International Journal of Artificial Intelligence in Education},
  number  = {11},
  pages   = {47--78},
  title   = {{Animated pedagogical agents: face-to-face interaction in 
              interactive learning environments}},
  volume  = {Internatio},
  year    = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[round]{natbib} % <==========================================
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{A}{References2}

\begin{document}
Reference without prefix \cite{Creighton2006} and a reference with 
prefix \citeA{Johnson2000}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % <========================================
\bibliography{\jobname}

\bibliographystyleA{plainnat} % <=======================================
\bibliographyA{A} % <===================================================
\end{document}
```

and the usual compiling chain

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe.aux
bibtex A.aux
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

gives me the following result without errors:

[image: resulting pdf]